# Number or String while setting style values with javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization

There are some `css` values that is defined with a number, such as `opacity`

I know while writing css, I would do:

```
#element {
  opacity: 1; /* without a quote mark, just 1 */
}
```

But when I am going to modify that `opacity` with javascript, what should I provide ? only `0.5` or `"0.5"` ?

if I run:

```
typeof document.getElementById('element').style.opacity // returns "srting"
```

So I used to provide string while modifying that.
But someone reviewing my code, suggested me to provide number like:

```
document.getElementById('element').style.opacity = 0.5
```

What type should actually be used here while modifying it with javascript ? String or Number ?

Comment: according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/opacity), it's a numerical value. maybe it is stored internally as string.

Comment: **all** css properties that belongs to a `CSSStyleDeclaration` interface (read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) actually are strings. You may answer your question by rather logging `document.getElementById('element').style`. That said, you can use either a string, either a number, since the setter will handle both, converting the numeric value to a string.

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't read that language

Comment: @Towkir replace "de" with "en" in the URL to read the english version. Besides, read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty . As you can see, the argument is a `DOMString`, so values are technically UTF-16 strings.

Comment: @briosheje Thanks, I know how to do that, I am a contributor at MDN myself, I was just trying to imply that someone should share English references in a platform like StackOverflow. :)

Comment: sorry, it should be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz, BTW, the value is a number as long as it's provided in a CSS, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity#Formal_syntax
But the moment I am trying to access or modify it via JS, it becomes an object with strings. Just figured it out now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All css values are strings (technically, `DOMString`s), therefore it's cleaner to use strings as well when you change them. Still, you can use numbers (or whatever) directly, JS will just do `.toString()` for you.

However, there are only a few unitless properties in css, for other numeric props you're required to provide a unit, and a bare number would be a mistake:

```
 style.opacity = "0.5" // fine
 style.opacity = 0.5   // fine

 style.width = "3px" // fine
 style.width = 3     // wrong!
```

So I'd make it a habit to always use strings with css.

Also, `document.getElementById('element').style` returns a huge object with all the possible css properties and their values which are strings:

example:

```
alignContent: ""
alignItems: ""
alignSelf: ""
alignmentBaseline: ""
all: ""
animation: ""
animationDelay: ""
```

Try it in your browser console on a valid element, you'll see it.
So I would suggest using strings.